# Accessing model and module methods in Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, rake

I am having some trouble accessing my module methods when running my Rake task, the error I get at the moment is

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CustomerTestimonialGrabber
```

I have set my module with class like so

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

module CustomerTestimonialGrabber
  class Grabber

    def perform
      get_testimonials
   end

   def get_testimonials
     url = 'http://www.ratedpeople.com/profile/lcc-building-and-construction'
     doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open url)

     testimonial_section = doc.css('.homeowner-rating.content-block:not(.main-gallery):not(:last-child)').each do |t|
      title = t.css('h4').text.strip
      comment = t.css('q').text.strip
      author = t.css('cite').text.strip
     end
    Testimonial.where(title: title, comment: comment, author: author).first_or_create!
   end
 end
end
```

My Rake task is set how I would normally

```
namespace :grab do
  task :customer_testimonials => :environment do
    CustomerTestimonialGrabber::Grabber.new.perform
  end
end
```

Could anyone explain why I am not able to access the module, I have also set this in my application.rb file

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

### Edit

I have done some more reading and have now required the module before running my rake task

```
require './lib/customer_testimonial_grabber/grabber.rb'
```

but now it seems I have trouble accessing the model itself

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `title' for #<CustomerTestimonialGrabber::Grabber:0x00000004be3878>
```

Comment: what do you mean 'model'? I don't see anything inheriting from Active Record here. Your error is because you're trying to call the title method on the Grabber class and it doesn't have that method. What line is triggering that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should put the Testimonial line INSIDE the preceding block?

```
testimonial_section = doc.css('.homeowner-rating.content-block:not(.main-gallery):not(:last-child)').each do |t|
      title = t.css('h4').text.strip
      comment = t.css('q').text.strip
      author = t.css('cite').text.strip
      Testimonial.where(title: title, comment: comment, author: author).first_or_create!   
end
```

Because title isn't defined outside of it.